# Equivant for EnableBuffering in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I'm working to migrate an Application Insights request body logging middleware from .NET Core to .NET Framework but I can't find how to re-write some things.

The middleware in .NET Core:

```
public class RequestBodyLoggingMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
     public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
     {
          var method = context.Request.Method;

          // Ensure the request body can be read multiple times
          context.Request.EnableBuffering();

          // Only if we are dealing with POST or PUT, GET and others shouldn't have a body
          if (context.Request.Body.CanRead && (method == HttpMethods.Post || method == HttpMethods.Put))
          {
               // Leave stream open so next middleware can read it
               using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false, bufferSize: 512, leaveOpen: true);

               var requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

               // Reset stream position, so next middleware can read it
               context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

               // Write request body to App Insights
               var requestTelemetry = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
               requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("RequestBody", requestBody);
          }

          // Call next middleware in the pipeline
          await next(context);
        }
}
```

I did the following changes:

- replaced `IMiddleware` with `OwinMiddleware`
- implemented constructor

  `public RequestBodyLoggingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }`
- changed `Invoke` method signature

  `public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)`
- replaced `HttpMethods.Post` with `HttpMethod.Post.Method`
- replaced `HttpMethods.Put` with `HttpMethod.Put.Method`.
- changed next method from `await next(context)` to `await Next.Invoke(context)`

So, until now I have the following result in .NET Framework:

```
public class RequestBodyLoggingMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
     public RequestBodyLoggingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

     public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
     {
          var method = context.Request.Method;

          // Ensure the request body can be read multiple times
          (*)----> context.Request.EnableBuffering();

          // Only if we are dealing with POST or PUT, GET and others shouldn't have a body
          if (context.Request.Body.CanRead && (method == HttpMethod.Post.Method || method == HttpMethod.Put.Method))
          {
               // Leave stream open so next middleware can read it
               using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false, bufferSize: 512, leaveOpen: true);

               var requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

               // Reset stream position, so next middleware can read it
               context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

               // Write request body to App Insights
               (*)----> var requestTelemetry = context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
               (*)----> requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("RequestBody", requestBody);
          }

          // Call next middleware in the pipeline
          await Next.Invoke(context);
     }
}
```

It's almost done, but I can't find how to re-write the `(*)---->` sections.

Regarding `context.Request.EnableBuffering()` I found [this article](https://markb.uk/asp-net-core-read-raw-request-body-as-string.html) and understood that this is not necessary in .NET Framework?

But I can't find any equivalent for:

- `context.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>()`
- `requestTelemetry?.Properties.Add("RequestBody", requestBody)`